# Convert object to Chartis.js structure

Tags: javascript, json, chartist.js

Can anybody help me with converting the following structure to a Chartist.js structure? I use chartis.js to show line chart. I need convert this JSON below to object structure.

```
<code>
data = {
    "el1": [{
        "date": "2017.01",
        "data1": {
            "series_1": {
                "a": 10,
                "b": 20,
                "c": 50,
                "d": 15,
                "e": 8
            },
            "Series_2": {
                "yes": 5,
                "no": 3
            },
            "Series_3": {
                "s": 2,
                "n": 9
            }
        },
        "text": [{
            "t": "header",
            "c": "text"
        }, {
            "t": "header2",
            "c": "text2"
        }]
    }, {
        "date": "2017.02",
        "data1": {
            "series_1": {
                "a": 56,
                "b": 23,
                "c": 45,
                "d": 69,
                "e": 14
            },
            "Series_2": {
                "yes": 2,
                "no": 1
            },
            "Series_3": {
                "s": 6,
                "n": 4
            }
        },
        "text": [{
            "t": "header",
            "c": "text"
        }, {
            "t": "header2",
            "c": "text2"
        }]
    }, {
        "date": "2017.03",
        "data1": {
            "series_1": {
                "a": 15,
                "b": 12,
                "c": 10,
                "d": 54,
                "e": 4
            },
            "Series_2": {
                "yes": 20,
                "no": 16
            },
            "Series_3": {
                "s": 9,
                "n": 7
            }
        },
        "text": [{
            "t": "header",
            "c": "text"
        }, {
            "t": "header2",
            "c": "text2"
        }]
    }
    ]
};
</code>
```

And I Need Object like this:

```
<code>
var example = [ 
{ 
labels: ['2017.01', '2017.02', '2017.03'] , series: [10,56,15], [20,23, 12], [50,45,10], [15, 69, 54], [8,14,4]}, 
labels: ['2017.01', '2017.02', '2017.03'] , series: [5,2,20], [3,1, 16]}, 
labels: ['2017.01', '2017.02', '2017.03'] , series: [2,6,9], [9,4, 7]}, 
] ; 
</code>
```

Please check the digit's and tray to comapre JSON and Output to better understand how to should look's like. Sorry for my English !
Thanks for the help! Best regards!

Comment: In your output `series: [ [s, nn],` where is this `nn` coming from?

Comment: At least post the logic which is resulting in this output!

Comment: sorry my mistake it must be: var example = {
        labels: ['2017.01', '2017.02'],
        series: [
            [a, b, c, d, e],
            [a, b, c, d, e]
        ]],
    {
        labels: ['2017.01', '2017.02'],
        series: [
            [yes, no],
            [yes, no]
        ]], , {
        labels: ['2017.01', '2017.02'],
        series: [
            [s, n],
            [s, n]
        ]]
};

Comment: Can you edit the question itself along with adding the logic?

Comment: Your example is still not a valid JSON. It is wrapped in `{ .. }` but you are treating it as an `array`. Please check that first..

Comment: When i use https://jsonlint.com ,  it's valid. I need structure like in var Example because i use https://gionkunz.github.io/chartist-js/ lib to show data in line chart.

Comment: Try pasting this `{
        labels: ['2017.01', '2017.01'],
        series: [
            [a, b, c, d, e],
            [a, b, c, d, e]
        ]],
    {
        labels: ['2017.01', '2017.01'],
        series: [
            [yes, no],
            [yes, no]
        ]], , {
        labels: ['2017.01', '2017.01'],
        series: [
            [s, nn],
            [s, n]
        ]]
};` it is not a valid json

Comment: Yes You have right ! Now is ok var example = [
{
    labels: ['2017.01', '2017.02']
    , series: [[a, b, c, d, e], [a, b, c, d, e]]
}, 
{
    labels: ['2017.01', '2017.02']
    , series: [[yes, no], [yes, no]]
}
, 
{
    labels: ['2017.01', '2017.02']
    , series: [[s, n], [s, n]]
}
]
;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just iterate the array and can manipulate it to the result you are looking for...

```js
function getFormatted(data) {
  var _newData = {};
  var allSeries = [];
  data.el1.forEach(function(el){
    _newData[el.date] = el.data1;
    if(allSeries.length==0)
      allSeries = Object.keys(el.data1);
  });
  
  return allSeries.map(function(el) {
    var obj = {
      labels: [],
      series: []
    };
    obj.labels = Object.keys(_newData);
    Object.keys(_newData).forEach(function(_el) {
      obj.series.push(Object.keys(_newData[_el][el]));
    });
    var _newSeries = [];
    obj.series[0].forEach(function(el, i){
      _newSeries.push([el, obj.series[1][i]]);
    });
    obj.series = _newSeries;
    return obj;
  });
}

var data = {
  "el1": [{
    "date": "2017.01",
    "data1": {
      "series_1": {
        "a": 1,
        "b": 2,
        "c": 3,
        "d": 4,
        "e": 5
      },
      "Series_2": {
        "yes": 1,
        "no": 2
      },
      "Series_3": {
        "s": 1,
        "n": 2
      }
    },
    "text": [{
      "t": "header",
      "c": "text"
    }, {
      "t": "header2",
      "c": "text2"
    }]
  }, {
    "date": "2017.02",
    "data1": {
      "series_1": {
        "a2": 1,
        "b2": 2,
        "c2": 3,
        "d2": 4,
        "e2": 5
      },
      "Series_2": {
        "yes2": 1,
        "no2": 2
      },
      "Series_3": {
        "s2": 1,
        "n2": 2
      }
    },
    "text": [{
      "t": "header",
      "c": "text"
    }, {
      "t": "header2",
      "c": "text2"
    }]
  }]
};

console.log(getFormatted(data));
```

Comment: Tkanks ! Your code works perfect ! Unfortunately I made mistake, the Output shuld looks like this:

Comment: var example = [ 
{ labels: ['2017.01', '2017.02'] , series: [[a from date "2017.01", a from date "2017.02"], [b from date "2017.01", b from date "2017.02"], [c from date "2017.01", c from date "2017.02"],[d from date "2017.01", d from date "2017.02"], [e from date "2017.01", e from date "2017.02"]}, 
{ labels: ['2017.01', '2017.02'] , series: [[yes from date "2017.01", yes from date "2017.02"],[no from date "2017.01", no from date "2017.02"]},
{ labels: ['2017.01', '2017.02'] , series: [[s from date "2017.01", n from date "2017.02"],[s from date "2017.01", n from date "2017.02"]},
] ;

Comment: Could You Help again. Please and sorry. You made great job but I  made mistake :(

Comment: @breakbit can you update the output in the question. It is hard to read here. And what does `a from date "2017.01"` means?

Comment: Thanks for your help but this time someting go wrong I update first post and give you advise. I made new JSON Please compare digits from keys and data output in var Example to bettter understand my structure.